# Xamarin.iOS Debugging not working

Tags: xcode, debugging, xamarin, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2017

I have a very simple Xamarin.iOS project working on Visual Studio on Windows 10, the project contains two text box and one button.

Whenever I click on Debug (Iphone X iOS 11.4) Visual Studio start to build the application, then I receive the success message:

> ========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ========== Build started. Build succeeded.

Then nothing happens!! If I click on Start Without Debugging, the simulator will popup and the application will run but without debugging!

I tried to run the application first without debugging, the click start debugging but still, with no luck.

Versions I'm using (All of them are updated to the latest version):

On Windows:
Visual Studio Community 2017, V 15.7.4

On Mac Host: Visual Studio7.5.3, 
Xcode: 9.4.1

Comment: What is your linker behavior set to in the iOS project?    I ran into something similar, and read where it says setting it to anything other than don't link may 'hinder debugging'

Comment: @PatrickGoode tried to change it to "Link All" and to "Link Framework SDKs Only" and still the same

Comment: Does this issue occur on both Winodws and MAC? Have you right click on your iOS project and select "Set As Starting Project" when you debugging on windows?

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT it's working on MAC, but not Windows! and yes, I selected the project as starting project.

Comment: Even if a blank new project still have this issue?

Comment: @Alex yes, I just tried with blank new project with the same result :(

Comment: @AKO, That's weird, it works fine on my windows. To narrow down this issue, have you tried to debugging it on another machine, check if still have this issue? If not, this issue should be related to your Visual Studio or some settings, you can try to repair or reinstall Visual Studio.